# How to get the first image from post?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I get the first image from post whith this code:

```
function first_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content,    $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

if(empty($first_img)){
$images = array(
     'white5px.jpg',
 );
$image  = $images[array_rand($images)];
$first_img = "/wp-content/themes/tabs/images/" . $image . "";
}
return $first_img;}
?>

<img src="<?php echo first_image() ?>"title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

Everything works fine except when I use the galery - the image not displayed.
Live example:http://beardhouse.com.ua/?cat=2 Why it doesn't work and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: well it cant find your white5px.jpg for starters. Its not in that folder where it should be. 

((http://beardhouse.com.ua/wp-content/themes/tabs/images/white5px.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine except when I use the galery - the image not
>   displayed.

Galleries are not stored in the post body as full `img` tags, which is what your regex looks for. A gallery is saved to the post body as a shortcode which is processed on display and transformed into the gallery you see.

That is, if you `echo $post->post_content` what you will see is something like this:

```
[gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]
```

The quick and dirty solution would be to process that shortcode before your regex gets involved.

```
$content = do_shortcodes($post->post_content);
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
```

I can't help but think that that is a somewhat clumsy and inefficient solution. Most images in WordPress are "attachments" to the post, so you might be better off querying for attachments directly, as per this [example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children):

```
function echo_first_image( $postID ) {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $postID,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );

    $attachments = get_children( $args );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) : wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

            echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current">';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get First Image of Post Enter this code in Function.php file

```
 function catch_that_image(){
 global $post, $posts;
 $first_img = '';
 ob_start();
 ob_end_clean();
 $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches); $first_img = $matches [1] [0];if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";}return $first_img;}
```

}

add this code in post loop